# select unique rows sorted by id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

Table A

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| pid | name    | country |
+-----+---------+---------+
|  1  | ABC     | XXXXXXX |
|  2  | EFG     | YYYYYYY |
|  3  | IJK     | ZZZZZZZ |
|  4  | LMN     | AAAAAAA |
|  5  | OPQ     | BBBBBBB |
|  6  | RST     | CCCCCCC |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

Table B

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | pid     |
+-----+---------+
|  5  |   5     | 
|  4  |   1     | 
|  3  |   2     | 
|  2  |   5     | 
|  1  |   2     |
+-----+---------+
```

I want the below output

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| pid | name    | country |
+-----+---------+---------+
|  5  | OPQ     | BBBBBBB |
|  1  | ABC     | XXXXXXX |
|  2  | EFG     | YYYYYYY |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

That is the output should get the latest entries of Table B id field and the data of table A should be shown on appearing sequence of pid from Table B

Comment: Please share the script also for sample data

Comment: It will be easy to provide and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to both join the tables together and to get the most recent value.  Here is one method:

```
select a.pid, a.name, a.country
from a join
     b
     on a.pid = b.pid
where b.id = (select max(b2.id) from b b2 where b2.pid = b.pid);
```

Comment: Hey, this one has been worked with my update question.Thank you so much @Gordon

Comment: select a.pid, a.name, a.country
from a join
     b
     on a.pid = b.pid
where b.id = (select max(b2.id) from b b2 where b2.pid = b.pid) order by b.id desc;

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PID, A.NAME, A.COUNTRY
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.PID = B.PID
ORDER BY A.PID
```

Comment: Should that be ORDER BY ID ?

Comment: No @sniperd because they aren't returning any rows from table_b, thus an aggregate and order by isn't needed, although PID just makes it match the expected results (despite the title of the post). if they wanted table_b id then Gordon's answer would be most ideal.

Comment: Thanks guys for such a quick respond.

Comment: Actually the sorting is needed as per the data appeared on table B pid... I understand the confusion, after posting the question. If the PID appears in table B as 5,1,2,5,2 then the expected output is, 5,1,2 from table A. Updating the question

Comment: @scsimon you were right on Gordor's answer. It resolved the ordering issue

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a join or fields from B?

```
SELECT a.pi, a.name, a.country
FROM A AS a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT b.id FROM B AS b WHERE b.pid = a.pid)
```

Comment: Here also the issue with maintaining the order. Sorted data should be as per order by B.id

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t1.*
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t2.pid = t1.pid
order by row_number() over (partition by t2.pid order by t2.id desc);
```